# How to make the default color theme in MUI transparent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, background-color

I wanted to set the background color of an element to be the primary main color  but with transparency  using Material-UI,  tried to do it the following ways but both hasn't worked , any suggestion i would highly appreciate it.

```
backgroundColor: `rgba(${theme.palette.primary.main}, 0.6)`,
```

&

```
background: `rgba(${theme.palette.primary.main}, 0.6)`,
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow your pattern but instead on using rgba add any one of [this link](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4) values to your theme color.

e.g. for 9% transparency use `17`:

```
backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.primary.main}17`,
```

*Copied from the link above:*

**All hex value from 100% to 0% alpha:**

100% — FF

99% — FC

98% — FA

97% — F7

96% — F5

95% — F2

94% — F0

93% — ED

92% — EB

91% — E8

90% — E6

89% — E3

88% — E0

87% — DE

86% — DB

85% — D9

84% — D6

83% — D4

82% — D1

81% — CF

80% — CC

79% — C9

78% — C7

77% — C4

76% — C2

75% — BF

74% — BD

73% — BA

72% — B8

71% — B5

70% — B3

69% — B0

68% — AD

67% — AB

66% — A8

65% — A6

64% — A3

63% — A1

62% — 9E

61% — 9C

60% — 99

59% — 96

58% — 94

57% — 91

56% — 8F

55% — 8C

54% — 8A

53% — 87

52% — 85

51% — 82

50% — 80

49% — 7D

48% — 7A

47% — 78

46% — 75

45% — 73

44% — 70

43% — 6E

42% — 6B

41% — 69

40% — 66

39% — 63

38% — 61

37% — 5E

36% — 5C

35% — 59

34% — 57

33% — 54

32% — 52

31% — 4F

30% — 4D

29% — 4A

28% — 47

27% — 45

26% — 42

25% — 40

24% — 3D

23% — 3B

22% — 38

21% — 36

20% — 33

19% — 30

18% — 2E

17% — 2B

16% — 29

15% — 26

14% — 24

13% — 21

12% — 1F

11% — 1C

10% — 1A

9% — 17

8% — 14

7% — 12

6% — 0F

5% — 0D

4% — 0A

3% — 08

2% — 05

1% — 03

0% — 00

Comment: Great solution. If you're using hex colors, make sure you write out all 6 digits, even for basic colors like white and black. This solution won't work if you write the shorthand (white being #FFF won't work, but #FFFFFF will work, and same for black).

Answer (score 1):

A solution which I have used for this before is to handle the transparent color in the theme.

so for example in one of my projects I define the theme.palette.primary.main color at the top of my theme and then I calculate a lighter variant using the rgba function as you have done in your example as well. I then define this color in my theme so I can reuse it in multiple places by calling theme.palette.primary.light (or whatever you wish to call it).

and then